# Does stackoverflow.com use gitorious?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Does stackoverflow.com uses gitorious?  I'm curious to know.

Comment: This should be posted on meta

Comment: Wny is a Duran Duran song now playing in my head???

Answer (score 1):

No. They use [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln) instead.